# What controls the terminal pod access in Openshift Web Console?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

Who has access to open pod terminals through the openshift web console? What permissions need to be given for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any user that has `edit` or `admin` role in the project which the application is running in, can create a terminal session for pods running in that project.

```
oc adm policy add-role-to-user edit <collaborator>
```

The purpose of the different roles you can grant are:

- admin - A project manager. The user will have rights to view any resource in the project and modify any resource in the project except for quota. A user with this role for a project will be able to delete the project.
- edit - A user that can modify most objects in a project, but does not have the power to view or modify roles or bindings. A user with this role can create and delete applications in the project.
- view - A user who cannot make any modifications, but can see most objects in a project.

A user with `view` role cannot create a terminal session as that would mean they could modify things.

Comment: Also what is the difference between admin and edit perms?